# Setting.RetryLimit not working with CombinedSignInAndSignUp Orchestration Step

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using a `CombinedSignInAndSignUp` OrchestrationStep in order to sign in my user.

I want to implement a retry limit on that page and I am using the following custom policy:

Journey:

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
  <ClaimsProviderSelections>
    <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
  </ClaimsProviderSelections>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignIn-Email" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Self-Asserted Page:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <!-- This technical profile uses a validation technical profile to authenticate the user. -->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
      <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignin</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.forgotPasswordLinkLocation">none</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.showSignupLink">false</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.retryLimit">2</Item>           
      </Metadata>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />       
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="API-GetUserByEmailAddress" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

The validation technical profiles not have the `setting.retryLimit` set.

This is what I see when I run my policies:

[image: Failing to sign in and the settings for the Azure AD B2C page]

There are two settings for `retryLimit`. The retry limit does not work and the user is allowed to enter as many incorrect username and password combinations as they like.

How would I implement a retry limit on `CombinedSignInAndSignUp` OrchestrationStep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using retryLimit here. retryLimit will only work on pure selfAsserted technical profiles. It will not work on the combined sign in and sign up page.

If you want to protect credential attacks, this is already enabled by default:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/threat-management

Comment: What do you mean by 'pure' selfAsserted technical profiles? How would one make one sign-in flow allow more attempts than another? Or not allow infinite attempts?

Comment: A pure selfAsserted tech profile is one that is that is *not* being used for a “combined sign in and sign up” step. Sign in attempts should be limited using smart lockout. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/threat-management. The retry limit should be used to really just prevent generic input pages from being abused.